# How do I create a figure displaying a stack of images at an angle?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I am attempting to create a figure of a similar nature to 
[image: this].

I have attempted to use perspective transforms in OpenCV or image transformations in skimage.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
from skimage import transform

# Load the image as a matrix
image = io.imread("/path/to/your/image.jpg")

# Create affine transform
afine_tf = skimage.transform.AffineTransform(shear=0.2)

# Apply transform to image data
modified = skimage.transform.warp(image, inverse_map=afine_tf)
```

Unfortunately I cannot achieve the desired effect with the perspectives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use perspective transform:

[image: output]

You will have to change this script so that it uses your images instead of generating images that are a solid color:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Generate some images
images = []
w, h = 600,700
# Corners of images to be pasted onto background
pts2 = np.float32([[0,0],[w,0],[0,w],[w,w]])
for i in range(5):
    img = np.zeros((w,w,3), np.uint8)
    img[:,:,:] = i*42, 255, 255
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    images.append(img)

# Create a background
bg = np.zeros((w,h,3), np.uint8)

# Define where to paste the images
top, bottom, dx, width, middle, left_buffer = 100, 500, 100, 200, 300, 50
# Create a mask
mask = np.zeros((w,w), np.uint8)
mask[:] = 255
bg_zeros = np.zeros_like(bg)

# Paste the images onto the background
for i in range(5):
    # Get the image
    img = images[i]
    # Compute where to paste the image
    left = left_buffer+dx*i
    right = left_buffer+dx*i + width
    mid = int((left + right)/2)
    pts1 = np.float32([[mid, top], [right, middle],
                       [left, middle], [mid, bottom]])
    # Warp the image
    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts2,pts1)
    dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,(h,w))
    # Warp the mask and mask out the background
    cmask = cv2.warpPerspective(mask, M, (h,w))
    bg = cv2.bitwise_and(bg,bg,mask = 255-cmask)
    # Add the image to the background
    bg += dst
cv2.imshow('bg', bg)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Interesting idea. Nice solution.